# When decoding the qr code, the program stops at the opening of the photo. Separate function works

Tags: python, decode, telegram-bot, qr-code

`Saving photo:`

```
def save_photo(photo): #saving photo
        file_info = bot.get_file(photo.photo[len(photo.photo) - 
        1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = 'photos/qr_photo.jpg'
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file: #opening photo
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

`The bot takes a photo and decodes it:`

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def decode(photo): #receives a message with a photo
    save_photo(photo) #saving photo from message
    sourse = 'photos/qr_photo.jpg'
    img = Image.open(sourse) #open photo        
    decoded_img = decode(img) #decoding and programm stop
    print(decoded_img)
    print(decoded_img[0].data.decode("utf-8"))
    bot.send_message(photo.chat.id, decoded_img[0].data.decode("utf- 
    8"), parse_mode='html') #send message
    os.remove(sourse)
```

**If the function is run separately, then it works correctly. When the bot executes it, the program stops and nothing happens.Please help**

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: telegram may use `try/except` to catch all errors and hide them.  You may need to use own `try/except` to check if there is error in this line. Eventually you can search if there is option to display all errors.

Comment: in Python you can use `photo.photo[-1]` instead of `photo.photo[len(photo.photo) - 1]`

Comment: maybe code runs in different folder than you expect and it doesn't have access to folder `photos`. You should try to use `/full/path/to/photos/qr_photo.jpg`. And you could check `Current Working Directory` - `print( os.getcwd() )`

Comment: I tried to use try/expect and print_debuging. But the problem is that the code does not turn off, but stops working further, without displaying errors.

Comment: I check. Program stops at decoding.  but if you run this in a separate file (not in the main code) and import it, then everything works

Comment: inside `decode()` you runs `decode()` - so maybe it runs in endless loop. Maybe yoo should rename function.